# how can i trigger webflow event with "onclick" remoteFunction in grails

Tags: javascript, grails

for example this checkBox click can trigger webflow event

```
<td><g:checkBox name="isSelected" value="${contestantInstance.id}" checked="false"     onclick="${remoteFunction(action:'selectCheck',_eventID:Next id:contestantInstance.id,
                    params:'\'isSelected=\' + this.checked')}"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

Since no one has answered up to now, I might give it a try.

This code works for me.

Javascript code that goes in  tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function enableText(checkBool, textId)
        {
            textFldObj = document.getElementById(textId);
            //Disable the text field
            textFldObj.disabled = !checkBool;
            //Clear value in the text field
            if (!checkBool) { textFldObj.value = ''; }
        }

    </script>
```

The checkBox and the onclick event is

```
    <td><g:checkBox checked="false" name="allVideos" value="${videoInstance.id}" onclick="enableText(this.checked, '${videoInstance.id}');" /></td>
```

N.B. videoInstance is the name of the var in the loop: